# How can I transfer data on play framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework, dataflow

I want to create single page application and I am beginner at play framework. I install the play activator and create play-java project then I import the project in eclipse. I put my login.html and necessary js files (index.js, controller.js etc) under the /public files. 
These login.html is simple form page which take data with angularjs.First step, I want to pass these data (login pages data's e.g. username, password) to play area. How can I do that? Another question is How can I respond these data very simple. At first step I should just send user data login.Html to play layer and take respond the one message on console ("success" etc.) for learning what's going on in play.If I accomplish that I think I can move on play framework to databases. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

> I want to pass these data (login pages data's e.g. username, password) to play area. How can I do that?

What you are trying to do is this.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Samples#Forms

There's no a simple response for that. If I would try to explain you here, I would have to write a Play Framework book, and there are a lot of them ;-)

So, you need to learn how to develop Play Framework applications since scratch. Look for the Play Framework documentation, or if you don't have patience, a book could helps you on your first steps.

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-text&field-keywords=play+framework